# How can I add remaining alphabets into this query in IGrouping<string,Topic>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group the items based on first alphabet of the word and this below query works fine. But I want to modify it and include all letters to this grouping irrespective of whether the item exists or not. How can I solve this?

The query is :-

```
  var qry = from row in item.Topics
                              group row by row.Title[0].ToString().ToLower() into groupedItems
                              orderby groupedItems.Key
                              select new Group<Topic>(groupedItems.Key, groupedItems);
```

Comment: Can you give more details, perhaps an example of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do an outer join on to the range a,b,c,... z?

There are a few ways of doing this. For example, you could try:

```
        var qry = from row in "LifeLikeThis"
                  group row by row.ToString().ToLower()
                  into groupedItems
                  orderby groupedItems.Key
                  select new {Key = groupedItems.Key, Items = groupedItems};

        var alphaQry = from character in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                       join grp in qry on character.ToString() equals grp.Key into joined
                       from joinGroup in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new {Key = character.ToString(), Items = joinGroup == null ? null : joinGroup.Items};
```

The key part of this is the `joined.DefaultIfEmpty()`. For more info on outer joins, see 101 samples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#leftouterjoin